# What is that decimal can't do but double can and vice versa?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, decimal

Can someone tell what a decimal variable cannot do but at the same time double can do?

Also what is that double cant do but decimal can?

I was having trouble with finding   power of  (sqroot 5)  to more than 2000000

e.g. (3 + root(5) )raise to 300000 ...here what can be used while using binomial expansion ?

Can I use double /  decimal ?  What's the main difference?

Note : I want to preserve last 3 decimal place before decimal point in the answer to the 100% accuracy.

Comment: Neither double nor decimal are in any way suitable for the kind of heavy-duty math calculation you describe. Double is good for representing the height of a building; decimal is good for representing the cost of a building; neither have a precision or range necessary for the kind of algebraic manipulation you want. Consider using Waterloo Maple or Mathematica or some other special-purpose math system.

Comment: @Eric lippert , thanks much. Actually i was solving google code jam puzzle ([link](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p2) ) and i went into trouble of calculating this heavy duty math ops.  Is there is any langguage which can directly (without any nasty logic of truncating decimal places ..etc..) calculate this heavy math ?   Is c# not suitable for this operations ?

Answer (score 9):

In brief:

- [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) is a decimal floating point type, so it can represent exact decimal values, e.g. 0.1. It has a fairly high precision, but a relatively limited *range*. It's implemented in software, so is relatively slow.
- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx)/[`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) are *binary* floating point types, so they can only represent exactly numbers which can be represented exactly in binary - which doesn't include the decimal value 0.1, for example. They have relatively low precision, but a large range. It's usually implemented in hardware, so is very fast.

Additionally `float`/`double` have representations for positive and negative infinity, and "not a number" - `decimal` doesn't have any of this.

See my articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information.

Comment: And Decimal is more precise, because it is larger - it can hold more info (96 bits of data vs 53 for double). It's also a lot slower.

Comment: That's why I said Decimal has a fairly high precision, and Float/Double have a relatively low precision. Will edit around speed though.

Comment: @Jon skeet , thanks for quick and meaninful reply. Your statement tells  exactly the difference between float and decimal but it will be great if you can elaborate with an example the situation  where to use decimal (other than o.1 example).  In the case of calculating the value of (3+root 5) raise to 300000 and where i want to have last 3 decimal numbers before decimal point (e.g. 23434888.42343 here i want 888 to be  100% accurate)

Comment: @dnkulkarni: Generally, you use `double` for scientific calculations for natural values (e.g. height, speed etc) and `decimal` for business calculations for artificial values - primarily money - where you really can have *exactly* $0.01, for example. There are various other Stack Overflow questions around this too.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was trying to say that the ONLY reason for the higher precision is the number of bits. Some people seem to think that `decimal`calculations are always exact, while `double` are not, e.g. that if you divide a `double` by 32 and then multiply by 32, you may have lost some bits of precision. Things like that.

Comment: @MrLister: Well, the number of bits used *for the mantissa*. You could have a type which is the same size as `double`, with a smaller range but more precision, by adjusting how many bits are used for what. But yes, I agree that the "decimal is exact, double is approximate" posters usually don't know what they're talking about :)

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal.MaxValue = 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335

double.MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308

(5.24) ^ 300000 = ???
```

I don't think you can easily raise 5 to the power of 300000 without using a math library that is more cleaver than double....

Answer (score 0):

decimal is base 10 which means he can represend 0.1 as 0.1

double is a base 2  - binary - which means he cant. ( its infinite numbers of 0,1)

double can store much bigger numbers than decimal

decimal is more accurate.,

Comment: Why did you say "infinite"? You shouldn't have.

Comment: @MrLister try to siaply 0.1 with binary. the example was about the 0.1

Comment: Yes, but "infinite" is wrong. You can express any `double` value with a finite number of decimals. Even if the number of decimals may be in the hundreds.

Comment: @MrLister Royi was saying that double cannot represent 0.1 exactly, because the binary representation of one tenth is an infinitely-repeating sequence.  Every binary fraction can be finitely represented as a decimal, but not vice versa.

Comment: @phoog - Until he will try - he wont understand this is how 0.1 is represented in float/double : ( base 2 ) :0.00011001100110011001100110011001..........http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

Comment: @RoyiNamir But I understand perfectly. 0.1 needs an infinite number of binary digits. Unfortunately, double doesn't have an infinite number of bits. And if you would have used an apostrophe in the proper place, I would have got what you meant immediately.